# Updating a file without allocating it in memory - IOS

Tags: objective-c, memory, malloc, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to sequentially overwrite bytes on an existing file filled with 0s.

I simply opened the file this way:

```
File *filePointer = fopen(filePath, "rb+");
```

and then I write in the file this way:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, length, filePointer);
```

where buffer is of type (const uint8_t *) and length is the size of the buffer it is going to write.

The problem I'm facing is that with large files (for example 500MB) I get a malloc error:

```
    malloc: *** mmap(size=570056704) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I think that it is because fwrite tries to load in memory the entire file that is too big for the iphone ram (the same code works in the simulator!!). With smaller files it works flawlessy on a real device too!

Can I update files without loading them in memory?

THank you

Andrea

Comment: I think a better approach would be spliting the original file into handleable chunks.

Comment: If you don't need any Stdio features then you could work with open(), write(), ... directly. - Or you can try to set a buffer size for Stdio with setvbuf().

Comment: @ender: unluckily, while I perform this write operation the file (a video) is read by a MPMoviePlayer and I don't know how I could make it work with chunks.

Comment: @MartinR: I tried using open and write but I get the very same malloc error. I guess that either write and fwrite load the file in memory. To be more specific I have to say that the malloc error pops up during the first call of fwrite/write and not opening the file pointer.

Comment: write() is a system call, therefore I do not know how that call can cause a malloc error.  Can you show your code using write() ? Can you single-step in the debugger to see exactly where the error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs during the first call of write (I checked it with the debugger). Another strange behavior is that setting setbuf to NULL, which should translate in an unbuffered operation directly on the filesystem, seems to have no effect. As soon as I am in front of the code I will publish thr write method I used and try to find some additional infos. Thanks a lot;)